# string tokenizer wrong usage in java

Tags: java, string, file, stringtokenizer

I believe I am not using correctly String Tokenizer. Here is my code:

```
  buffer = new byte[(int) (end - begin)];
                fin.seek(begin);
                fin.read(buffer, 0, (int) (end - begin));

                StringTokenizer strk = new StringTokenizer(new String(buffer),
                                DELIMS,true);
```

As you can see I am reading a chunk of lines from a file(end and begin are line numbers) and I am transfering the data to a string tokenizer. My delimitators are:

```
DELIMS = "\r\n ";
```

because I want to separate words that have a space between them, or are on the next line.
However this code sometimes separates whole words also. What could be the explanation?? Is my DELIMS string conceived wrong?

Also I am passing "true" as an argument to the tokenizer because I want the delimitators to be treated as tokens as well.( I want this because I want to count the line I am currently at)

Could you please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this action performed in a loop?

Comment: Please stop using StringTokenizer: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: This action is used by a number of threads, under the form of replicated workers

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this code that I am using and the string tokenizer I am trying to implement?

Comment: @biggdman - As 3 of us have already proposed the use of Scanner instead - which should eliminate the issues you're having with StringTokenizer (the use of which is discouraged by Java's own documentation), please detail why Scanner won't work for you instead.  If we better understand why and what you're looking for, then you should get some better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always wrap your input stream in a `LineNumberReader`. That will keep track of the line number for you. LineNumberReader extends `BufferedReader`, which has a `readLine()` method. With that, you could use a regular `StringTokenizer` to get your words as tokens. You could use regular expressions or `Scanner`, but for this case, StringTokenizer is simpler for beginners to understand and quicker.

You must have a RandomAccessFile. You didn't specify that, but I'm guessing based on the methods you used. Try something like:

```
byte [] buffer = ...; // you know how to get this.
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

// if you have java.util.Scanner
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(stream);

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        lineNum++;
        String line = s.nextLine();
        System.out.format("I am on line %s%n", lineNum);
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

        while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = lineScanner.next();
            // do whatever with word
        }
    }
}

// if you don't have java.util.Scanner, or want to use StringTokenizer
{
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.nextLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("I am on line " + reader.getLineNumber());
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = tok.nextToken();
            // do whatever with word
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To start with, your method for converting bytes into a String is a bit suspect, and this overall method will be less-than-efficient, especially for a larger file.

Are you required to use StringTokenizer?  If not, I'd strongly recommend using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead.  I'd provide you with an example, but will ask that you just refer to the Javadocs instead, which are quite comprehensive and already contain good examples.  That said, it accepts delimiters as well - but as Regular Expressions, so just be aware.